# Voice message save in aws s3 bucket using Amazon Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-connect

how to save voice message of customer number and store in an s3 bucket using aws connect. I made a contact workflow but I am not understanding how to save voice message to s3 bucket? [image]

Comment: We've tried many things to build a voicemail solution, including many of the things you might have found on the web.  After some time we realized that we had a product that would be useful to others.  For voicemail in Amazon Connect, take a look at [https://amazonconnectvoicemail.com](https://amazonconnectvoicemail.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've tried many ways to build a voicemail solution, including many of the things you might have found on the web.  After much iteration we realized that we had a product that would be useful to others.

For voicemail in Amazon Connect, take a look at https://amazonconnectvoicemail.com as a simple, no-code integration that can be customized to meet the needs of your customers and organization!

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you enabled `Voice Recording` all recordings are placed automatically in the bucket you defined at the very beginning as you setup your AWS Connect Instance. Just check your S3 Bucket if you can spot the recordings.

> By default, AWS creates a new Amazon S3 bucket during the
>   configuration process, with built-in encryption. You can also use
>   existing S3 buckets. There are separate buckets for call recordings
>   and exported reports, and they are configured independently.
>   (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/what-is-amazon-connect.html)

Comment: What are the s3 bucket features need to be configured here for permissions? Can you be specific in these areas?

Comment: What do you mean by `permissions`? The S3 bucket is already configured correctly (through AWS Connect). Did you already check your buckets to spot the AWS Connect bucket?

Comment: the s3 bucket working properly. but no voice is saving in s3 bucket.

Comment: A small quote out of the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/connect/faqs/). `Contact flow interactions are only recorded if an agent is listening to the call as well.` So did you agent listen to the call you want to record?

Comment: yes agent will listen to the call. How i can configure that in workflow?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I tried creating a flow and setting call recording behavior, but still not able to get a recording in S3 bucket. Can you please suggest how we can configure agent listen to the call we want to record in contact flow?

Comment: Calls are not recorded unless an agent is active on the call. If you want voicemail check out  https://amazonconnectvoicemail.com for the simplest solution

Answer (score 1):

The recording in S3 is only starting when an agent is taking the call. Currently, there is no direct voice mail feature in Amazon connect. You can forward the call to a service that allows it, such as Twillio.